# Example of L not regular language that suff(L) is regular

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I can't find example of L not regular language  that suff(L) is regular
I tried something like this:
{0^n1^n|n>= 0}, but i can't prove that it's suffix is regular

Suff(L) = {x ∈ Σ ∗ | ∃u ∈ Σ ∗ such that u · x ∈ L}.
[image]
thank you for the help :)

Comment: Since suffixes are just prefixes for the mirror language, the examples given in the answers to the following question are relevant: [Non-regular language whose prefix language is regular but not the whole set of words](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154128/4287)

Comment: The example $\{ 0^n 1^n \mid n\ge 0 \}$ from the question has suffixes that are non-regular: $\{ 0^k 1^n \mid n\ge k \ge 0 \} \cup 1^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L = \{ 0^n \mid n \text{ is prime}\}$.
Suppose towards a contradiction that $L$ is regular and let $p$ be a prime not smaller than the pumping length of $L$. The pumping lemma ensures that there is some $k$ such that $1 \le k \le p$ and $0^{p+ki} \in L$ for all $i \ge 0$. Choosing $i=p$ we have that $p+kp = p(k+1)$, which is not prime. We conclude that $L$ is not regular.

To show that $\textsf{Suff}(L)$ is regular, let $w = 0^{|w|}$ be any word in $\{0\}^*$. Since there is a prime $p \ge |w|$, we have that $0^{p-|w|} 0^{|w|} \in L$, therefore $w \in \textsf{Suff}(L)$. Then, $\{0\}^* \subseteq \textsf{Suff}(L) \subseteq \{0\}^*$, i.e., $\textsf{Suff}(L) = \{0\}^*$, which is clearly regular.

Comment: Thank you, that works,
Can you explain the thought process that led you to ponder this specific case?

Comment: I just wanted a language that included all possible words as a suffix to (trivially) satisfy the property that $Suff(L)$ is regular. The first non-regular language I could think of with this property was the language of prime-length strings. This is well-known to be non-regular.